# how to get php to read in a string of words from a dropdown box?

Tags: php, html

Thank you so much for being so helpful. Owe you all a thank you. I will be asking more questions in the future. Someone has solved the problem by giving me this code:
echo "" . strval($row['style']) . "" . "
";

and it worked beautifully!!!!!!!!! You rock!

I am sorry, I don't know how to post follow up questions, so I keep posting each question as a new question. I've never joined any forum before, so don't know how to follow a thread :( Sorry

I previously asked a question, but didn't post my code, so many kind people (thank you so much) who respanded couldn't help me out.

So I'll post my partial code below.

";
        echo "Select an item
";
        echo "";                          
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "$row[style] $row[color]
";    
    }

    mysql_close($con);

    echo "";
    echo "
";
    echo "Enter your 4 digit postcode
";
    echo "";
    echo "
";
    echo "Enter quantity
";
    echo "";
    echo "
";
    echo "";
    echo "";                 
?>

Then to process form, I use $_POST['item'] to find out which item was selected, I get the first word, the rest of the words are missing.

For example, if the dropdown box was populated with the follwoing:

Dressmaker mannequin size 12
Mannequin torso PH-9 in skin color
...

if item selected was "Dressmaker manenquin size 12", $_POST['item'] gives me Dressmaker, the rests are missing.

I spent whole last night and today searching, but have made no progress, please help :(

Comment: Just add a comment, or edit this question as opposed to posting new questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get php to read in a string of words from a dropdown box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011731/how-to-get-php-to-read-in-a-string-of-words-from-a-dropdown-box)

Comment: Something to note; Echoing out a bunch of static HTML is a waste of processing power and you're always bound to run into quoting difficulties. You should consider only dropping into the PHP context (`<?php ... ?>`) when required.

Comment: Also, your code above will be spitting out E_NOTICE errors due to missing quotes around the array keys. FYI, always reference associative array members using this syntax `$array['key']`

Comment: Thank you guys for all the help. I really appreciate it. One of the codes has fixed the problem. I am trying to use add comment to follow up with this thread,hope it shows up. I've never been on any forum in my entire life, so didn't know how to follow threads and post new questions instead. Really sorry about this. I also find my message/codes were chopped, and again I have no idea why because I just don't know how forum operates. The great thing is my problem is finally solved. Thank you all so much :)

Comment: I totally fail to see how `strval` has helped in this issue. The return value of `mysql_fetch_array` is "an array of **strings** that corresponds to the fetched row".

Comment: Why do you ask this question 3 times?

Comment: Because I didn't know how to follow it up so I asked another question again! I've never been on a forum in my entire life! I find it hard to believe myself. thanks to a few of you guys who gave me some tips. Hope I am doing the right thing now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This still applies from my previous post:

//====== Begin previous post

Hopefully, your MYSQL database has a primary key?  If it does, set the `value` of each `<option>` to the primary key of the item.

For example:

SQL

```
id  desc
1   "dressmaker thing with mannequin"
2   "dressmaker thing no mannequin"
```

Form PHP

```
echo "<option value='".$query['id']."'>".$query['desc']."</option>";
```

When the form is submitted, re-query the database for the desired description. You'll be doing this re-query anyway to retrieve prices and such, yes?

The reason this is happening is that spaces are discouraged in HTML attributes.  You shouldn't have an attribute like `value='this attribute is spaced'`.

//====== End previous post

Basically, change this line:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value=$row[style]>$row[style] $row[color]</option><br />";    
}
```

to

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>$row['style'] $row['color']</option><br />";    
}
```

and add this in `process_form.php` to get the description:

```
$desc = mysql_query("SELECT style FROM products WHERE id='".$_POST['item']."';");
```

You can also use this to get all other related info from the DB right when you need it.

// Another edit

@Cambraca - right on - I forgot to sanitize the quote.

@Ottoman - Your solution is a temporary fix. I strongly recommend applying an id/primary key system if it's not in place. An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.

Comment: Good answer, it's only missing mysql_real_escape_string so it avoids sql injection. So something like: $desc = mysql_query("SELECT style FROM products WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item'])."';");

Answer (score 0):

That is because in php you get what is in the "value" attribute of the dropdown's options.
You need to do something like this:

Replace

```
echo "<option value=$row[style]>$row[style] $row[color]</option><br />";
```

with

```
echo "<option value=\"$row[style] $row[color]\">$row[style] $row[color]</option><br />";
```

Comment: Thank you cambrac, it still gives me first word. My $row['style'] itself is more than one word. So even if I only use $row['style'] in the value attribute, it should still be more than one word. But it's giving me just the first word, please help again ...

Comment: Did you make sure you enclosed it in quotation marks? That's why I put the 2 \". Also, it would be best if you ran it through htmlspecialchars too so if there are quotation marks inside the string, it will not break the html.

Comment: I used echo "<option value=\"" . htmlentities($row['style']) . "\">" . strval($row['style']) . "</option>" . "<br />"; and it's working now. But I would like to take the advises of you guys and modify my db to put proper use of primary id :) As I type these  comments, i think I've come to understand what Steve and Phil meant by primary key id as the value for the value attribute. Marvo! Thank you so much! And thanks to Phil for pointing out that a fix here is a temporary fix, the long term solution lies in the primary key id :) Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your lack of quotes in the option "echo" statement.

Try something like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    printf('<option value="%s">%s %s</option>',
           htmlspecialchars($row['style']),
           htmlspecialchars($row['style']),
           htmlspecialchars($row['color']));
}
```

Note also, the `<br>` element does not belong in the `<select>`

Edit: Added `htmlspecialchars` to properly escape any HTML entities that might exist in retrieved strings

Comment: Thank you Phil, it still gives me first word. My $row['style'] itself is more than one word. So even if I only use $row['style'] in the value attribute, it's still more than one words. But it's giving me just the first word, please help again ...

Comment: Paste in the rendered HTML for the list of `<option>` elements. Also, see Steve's answer regarding primary keys as these would be much easier to use for item lookups.

Answer (score 0):

If it *gives you only the first word*, then you forgot to enclose the option `value="with quotes"`. Otherwise show us the constructed HTML source.